# Azure Synapse convert value in row

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In an Azure Synapse Dataflow, for every row where the field value in column "Name" starts with "F-" synapse, I want to change the value from column "Price" to an absolute value of the price.

Which Mapping data flow transformation can I use and which expression must I use?
I have tried the "alter Row" transformation but I couldn't get the expression done.

For example:

Original:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| P-12344 | -21354,45 |
| S-12335 | 12543,45 |
| F-13564 | 54,45 |
| F-112344 | -1254,45 |

Output:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| P-12344 | -21354,45 |
| S-12335 | 12543,45 |
| F-13564 | 54,45 |
| F-112344 | 1254,45 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use **derived column transformation** and `abs()` function in data flow.

Please go through the sample demonstration below:

**Source data:**

I have given String type to Name column and integer type to Price column in the projection of the source.

[image]

**Derived column transformation:**

Give the below expression

`iif(startsWith(Name,"F"),abs(Price),Price)`

[image]

**Result in Data preview:**

[image]

You can give the same source in the sink.